# changing font not working, is there a need to use the reshaper always in arabic fonts?

Tags: android, fonts, arabic

I am trying to change my arabic font in android app and I downloaded several fonts but when I added the below code the arabic letters stayed the same as if the font did not change although I downloaded different fonts with different letters style...

```
TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MyFont1.otf");
myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

plus I changed the font with a font editor so when I changed the bracket style it appeared as the new style when I added it to eclipse but when I changed a normal arabic letter nothing changed the letter appeared as it is with no modifications...

what's the cause? is there a need to use an arabic reshaper to do that or what's the cause? and how to solve it?

Comment: and you put your font-file in assets/fonts?

Comment: yes I did, and what is really bothering me is the لا because only its half appears... Do you use arabic fonts? and if yes please tell me how do you write your code to change the font and does your letters style change whenever you add a new font?

Comment: ok, so your font is applied, but not displayed correctly... i don`t use arabic fonts, sry. i think i cant help you. i misunderstood your question and thought your font did not appear on the device...

Comment: ok thank you anyway. anyway I solved the problem it was because of the font itself the fonts that I downloaded were not good fonts and oit seems that they were not accepted by the device... I downloaded others from another website and all is good now... thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution man because I'm having the same issue